# What is the difference between Microsoft.Samples.ServiceHosting.StorageClient and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am new to Azure and wondering what is the difference between Microsoft.Samples.ServiceHosting.StorageClient and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient?  Are both being used or should I just used the latter? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only use the latter.  The former is from a sample that shipped with the Windows Azure CTP in 2008... now there's an official storage client library (the second namespace you mentioned), and I would recommend always using that.